# checkbox list does not update in flutter getx

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

I am using GetX for the state management in flutter project. My problem is when I click on the checkbox it updates the state in controller but does not show the result in UI. In general the changed state should change the UI too. I am not sure what is the problem but I think there is a bug in using the observable variable in getx. How to solve this problem? If the post is not clear then please ask me.

This is the view.

```
class FilterBottomSheetWidget extends GetView<SearchController> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  height: Get.height - 90,
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 15, left: 4, right: 4),
          child: controller.expiringContractStatus.isEmpty ? CircularLoadingWidget(height: 100)
            : SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: ExpansionTile(
                      title: Text("Contract Status".tr, style: Get.textTheme.bodyText2),
                      children: List.generate(controller.expiringContractStatus.length, (index) {
                        var _expiringContractStatus = controller.expiringContractStatus.elementAt(index);
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
                          value: _expiringContractStatus["isCheck"], // ************
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            controller.itemChange(value, index); // ************
                            controller.update();
                          },
                          title: Text(
                            _expiringContractStatus["title"],
                            style: Get.textTheme.bodyText1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                            softWrap: false,
                            maxLines: 1,
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                      initiallyExpanded: true,
                    );
                  }                   
            )
        ),
      ),
     // more widgets
    ],
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

This is SearchController.

```
class SearchController extends GetxController {
final expiringContractStatus = <Map>[
  {
    "title": "aaa",
    "isCheck": false
  },
  {
    "title": "bbb",
    "isCheck": false
  },
  {
    "title": "ccc",
    "isCheck": false
  }        
].obs;

@override
void onInit() async {
  await refreshSearch();
  super.onInit();
}

void itemChange (bool value, int index) {
  expiringContractStatus[index]["isCheck"] = value; // *************
  update();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated Answer:

If you tried wrapping an an `Obx` and it didn't work, use `GetBuilder<SearchController>` instead.

```
GetBuilder<SearchController>(
    builder: (_) =>  controller.expiringContractStatus.isEmpty ? CircularLoadingWidget(height: 100)
            : SingleChildScrollView(...))
```

When you call `update()` it will trigger a rebuild no matter what, with the updated values. The only reason I can think of why `Obx` didn't work is that perhaps when it comes to lists in only responds to an addition or removal of an item in the list and not a change in a property nested inside.

In general, you'll probably find that in most cases using an observable stream based variable is not really needed. `GetBuilder` can handle most or all of what you need done unless you're doing something stream based (binding to an external Firebase collection for example). Nothing wrong with either, but `GetBuilder` is the most performant option as streams by their nature are a bit more expensive.

Original answer:

I suggest you read the docs regarding proper usage before claiming there's a bug in someone else's code. That goes for any package that you're using.

It's stated all over the `Readme` and in the basic counter app example that observable variables need to be placed in an `Obx` widget, otherwise there's nothing triggering a rebuild based on the updated state of an observable GetX variable.

The child of your `Container` should be

```
Obx(() => controller.expiringContractStatus.isEmpty ? CircularLoadingWidget(height: 100)
            : SingleChildScrollView(...))
```

Comment: Thanks. Loren, Before I post this problem I have tried with wrapping the scrollview with Obx. but could not solve the problem. :(

Comment: Ok, well with what you shared without an `Obx` or `GetBuilder` its definitely not gonna work, bug or no bug. See updated answer, `GetBuilder` should work.

Comment: Great. this is working. thanks. You are the expert in flutter.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.